# Java 8 nested list as singleton list in parent

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, java-stream

```
public class Parent {
    String name;
    List<Child> children;
}

public class Child {
    String childName;
}
```

I have these 2 classes by which my data set becomes as below:

```
List<Parent> parents = new ArrayList<>();

List<Child> _child1 = new ArrayList<>();
_child1.add(new B("p1c1"));
_child1.add(new B("p1c2"));
_child1.add(new B("p1c3"));
Parent p1 = new Parent("p1", _child1);
parents.add(p1);


List<Child> _child2 = new ArrayList<>();
_child2.add(new B("p2c1"));
Parent p2 = new Parent("p2", _child2);
parents.add(p2);
```

can there be some data by which we can convert this as below:

```
parents[
    parent1 {"p1", ["p1c1"]}, parent1 {"p1", ["p1c2"]}, parent1 {"p1", ["p1c3"]},
    parent2 {"p2", ["p2c1"]}
]
```

I want to break the nested list into singleton nested list, primary aim is to achieve this with streams api from java 8, also can you suggest the best approach for avoiding concurrentModification exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do:

```
parents.stream()
        .flatMap(parent -> parent.getChildren()
                            .stream()
                            .map(child -> new SimpleEntry<>(parent, child)))
        .map(pair -> new Parent(pair.getKey().getName(), 
                                Arrays.asList(pair.getValue())))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It's just creating a parent/child pair for each child, and then creating a **new** parent for each of those pairs, with the single child added to `children` field. That then gets collected into a `Parent` list.

Comment: To create a singleton list, you may use `Collections.singletonList` which does not need to create an array.

Comment: @Holger Thanks! Didn't know that.